# Envío un array con N cantidad de filas y en el backend no las recibo todas

Tags: php, php7

Envio una solicitud ajax de la sig manera:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    global: true,
    url: '192.168.0.150/api/imprimir',
    data: datos,
}).then(
    function(data) {
        alertify.notify('Comanda impresa','success');
    }, function(data) {
        console.log('this will run if the $.ajax fails');
        console.log('Error');
        console.log(data);
    }, function() {
        console.log('this will run if the deferred generates a progress update');
    }
);
```

Con un data json como este: ***[enlace a jsoneditoronline](https://jsoneditoronline.org/?id=d30347187a5340e8a576bf62b0e60318)***

En la cabecera de la solicitud veo que los envía todos:
[image: imagen]

Se ve que esta enviando las 63 posiciones.

Recibo los datos de la sig manera y los devuelvo:

```php
public function imprimir(Request $req) {
    try{
        return Response::json($req);
    }catch(Exception $e){
        return Response::json($e);
    }
}
```

Pero el backend no recibo todo el listado.
[image: error]

***Actualización 1:***

> La solicitud la hago a una API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posiblemente estés sobrepasando el límite de variables de entrada que tiene configurado el PHP de tu servidor. Revisa el `php.ini` o agrega un `phpinfo();` para checkar el valor máximo permitido.

> **`max_input_vars`**
>   Cuántas variables de entrada se pueden aceptar (el límite se aplica a $ _GET, $ _POST y $ _COOKIE superglobal por separado). El uso de esta directiva mitiga la posibilidad de ataques de denegación de servicio que usan colisiones hash. Si hay más variables de entrada que las especificadas por esta directiva, se emite una E_WARNING y otras variables de entrada se truncan de la solicitud.

Referencia en PHP net: 
http://php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-input-vars

Si el número predeterminado es 1000, y deseas aumentar este número a, digamos, 3000, debes poner en tu php.ini esta línea:

```php
max_input_vars = 3000
```

Si tu servidor usa el parche Suhosin (como por ej Apache en Debian), agrega también:

```php
suhosin.get.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.post.max_vars = 3000
suhosin.request.max_vars = 3000
```

Comment: Gracias hermano, efectivamente era eso.